# Java write all name into csv file

Tags: java, csv

- csv file (test.csv)
  Name|Gender
  Ali|M
  Abu|M
  Ahmad|M
  Siti|F
  Raju|M
- properties file (config.properties)
  IncomingFileName = test.csv
  OuputFileNameExtension = txt
- test1.java

  ```
  public class test1 {

  public static Properties prop1 = new Properties(); 

  public static String nameList;

  public test1() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
      InputStream input1 = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
      configProp.load(input1);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  
      test1 t1 = new test1();
      t1.readFileLength(configProp.getProperty("IncomingFileName"));   
  }

  public void readFileLength(String filename){

  File file = new File(filename);

  try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)){

      int j = 1;

      while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

          String line = scanner.nextLine() + " ";

          if (j != 1) {

              String[] records = line.split("\\|");
              String name = records[0];
              String gender = records[1];

              nameList = name;
          }
          j++;
      }

      if(j != 0){

              writeFile("file."+configProp.getProperty
              ("OutputFileNameExtension"),  nameList);
      }

      scanner.close();

  }catch(IOException x){
  }

  public void writeFile(String fileName, String nameList) throws IOException{

      File file = new File(fileName);
      FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);

      System.out.println(nameList); //show one name only

      fileWriter.flush();
      fileWriter.close();
  }
  ```
- From the above code, I want to write all the name into the csv file.
  However, I just can show 1 name only. (i.e Ali). How do I show all the 
  name in csv file?

Comment: Your code should show Raju not Ali.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that.

Comment: `nameList = name;` replaces the value everytime and so you will get Raju as output at the end of the while loop. Better store all the values in `list` or `map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a linked list of the names: replace `String nameList;` with `LinkedList<String> names = new LinkedList<>();`

add each name to the list : replace `nameList = name;` with `names.add(records[0]);`

then add the names to the new file:

```
public void writeFile(String fileName, List<String> names) throws IOException{

File file = new File(fileName);
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
for(String name: names){
    filewriter.write(name);//writes the current name to the file. you may need to add a /n or a "," to the name to get approprite line seperations and comas
}

fileWriter.flush();
fileWriter.close();
}
```

Comment: You should pass names as parameter to your method instead of nameList string.

Comment: Note: Instead of LinkedList better to use List, so that user can send any form of list.

Comment: touché. Changed it again

Answer (score 0):

How about change:

```
namelist = name
```

to

```
namelist = namelist + " " + name
```

and only calls the writeFile method one time.

Or you could declare namelist as a StringBuilder, and use the append() method to do the same thing.

Comment: Appending with space is bad idea. You don't know in what format OP want to store the data in txt file.